# JSTL in dynamic table creation

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl-functions

I am new to **Spring** framework. I want to build a form where user needs to choose some values from **select** list. I have write down the code in body part of jsp page. This works fine.

```
<select id="txtRelation1" name="txtRelation1">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${fn:length(lstMem) gt 0}">
            <c:forEach var="objRelation" items="${lstMem}" varStatus="status">
                <option value="${objRelation.id}">${objRelation.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</select>
```

Now I want to use same select box in dynamically created rows using **insertRow()**. Now I am stuck at this point. I am trying to append same code in javascript, but it thrown some error.

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<select id='txtRelation"+temp+"' name='txtRelation"+temp+"' >"+
    "<option value=''>Select one</option>"+
        "<c:choose>"+
        "   <c:when test="${fn:length(lstMem) gt 0}">"+
        "       <c:forEach var='objRelation' items="${lstMem}" varStatus='status'>"+
    "<option value="+${objRelation.id}+">"+${objRelation.name}+"</option>"+
        "       </c:forEach>"+
        "   </c:when>"+
        "</c:choose>"+
"</select></div>";
```

**Error**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>
> #### Validation error messages from
>   TagLibraryValidator for c in /WEB-INF/jsp/relationEntry.jsp
>
> 49:
>   Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: ""+
>                 ...".
>
> 53: Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: ""+

Can somebody helps me to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: did you think is this possible? because `jstl` code won't compile by javascript.

Comment: instead of using this try hide/show in your javascript/jquery

Comment: remember, the JSTL code runs on the server side, whereas the javascript code runs on the client side.

Comment: So what is the way to achieve this?